# Unable to import global variables in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables, global, python-import

All of the following is in one file:

```
def inner_foo(in_arg):
    global x;
    x += 99
    return in_arg + 1

def outer_foo(in_arg):
    global x;
    x = 0
    output = inner_foo(in_arg)
    return output    

result = outer_foo(5)
print("result == ", result)
print("x == ", x)
```

It works just fine when it is all in one file. Here is what gets printed:

```
result ==  6
x ==  99
```

However, if we try to split the program across multiple files, we run into problems.

```
# CONTENTS OF inner_foo.py
def inner_foo(in_arg):
global x;
x += 99
return in_arg + 1
```

Here is the other file:

```
# CONTENTS OF outer_foo.py
from inner_foo import inner_foo
def outer_foo(in_arg):
    global x
    x = 0
    output = inner_foo(in_arg)
    return output

result = outer_foo(5)
print("result == ", result)
print("x == ", x)
```

We get an error `NameError: name 'x' is not defined` on the line `x += 99` inside inner_foo.py

Changing the import statement to include x (`from inner_foo import inner_foo, x`) gives us:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'x'
```

Comment: Correct your format first please.

Comment: The bodies of your functions are not indented. There is no need for the semicolons after the global variables.

Answer (score 1):

Python "global" scope is actually *module-level*, as you inferred when you tried to import. The problem is, when you do `x += 1`, that is the equivalent to `x = x + 1`, but **`x`** has never been defined in your module. So, suppose we have `a.py`:

```
def f():
    global x
    x += 1
```

There is *no `x` in `a`, there is only `f`.* So now, let's open up a REPL:

```
>>> import a
>>> a.f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/juan/workspace/temp/globals_modules/a.py", line 3, in f
    x += 1
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

And, as stated above, "global scope" is actually module-level scope, so `f`'s global scope is module `a`'s namespace, not necessarily the caller's global scope, i.e.:

```
>>> x = 0
>>> a.f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/juan/workspace/temp/globals_modules/a.py", line 3, in f
    x += 1
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

So, actually, it is looking for `x` in `a`'s namespace, so if we do the following:

```
>>> a.x = 0
>>> a.f()
>>> a.x
1
>>> a.f()
>>> a.x
2
```

It works! So to put it as succinctly as possible:

```
>>> a.f.__globals__ is globals()
False
```

### However!

Now that you are armed with this knowledge, do **not** go down this design path. Relying on changing global state across modules is a path to sorrow. Don't do it, it isn't recommended because generations of coders have found this is bad. Redesign your approach, and you will build more robust, easier to reason-about, and less buggy software.